# pojo to hashmap with custom keys

Tags: java, marshalling, unmarshalling, ognl

How to convert a java pojo to hashmap( and reverse) not using field names but instead custom keys in an efficient manner. for instance;

```
Customer:                         
 - name = aaa
 - surname = bbb
```

will be converted to hashmap with keys below.

```
Hashmap:
- mykey1 : aaa
- mykey2 : bbb
```

The solution should be generic and work for different objects (there will be key to property mapping definitions like name -> mykey1, surname->mykey2) 
I have checked apache commons OGNL but did not quite understand how to get it work for such a situation.
Ps: I know this can be done with reflection, but I am asking a high level solution includings apis and frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

You should use reflection and just for each field find in your properties key and put into map.

Comment: Actually I was askling for a higher level solution.

Comment: It's just one loop, high level solutions use this